# Test Data prediction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
X_train = train_data_copy[['year', 'month','day', 'city', 'medicine', 'discounted']]
    
y_train = train_data_copy['sales']
    
X_test = test_data_copy[['year', 'month','day', 'city', 'medicine', 'discounted']]
    
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
    
dt_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    
dt_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
y_test_pred=dt_reg.predict(X_test)]
```

Comment: I have two CSV files, Train and Test. If my X_train=All the columns from train data, y_train=Target column in train data, X_test=All the columns from test data. then what should be my y_test

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate on what your problem was, as well as fix your code formatting? Thanks!